# How to log application crash and system crash using nodejs and express?

Tags: node.js, morgan

I am very happy with logging using npm module morgan but not sure how to log system crash or system shutdown in node application. Is it possible? Please guide.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Process API to watch for uncaught exceptions.

```js
process
  .on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
    // Use your own logger here
    console.error(reason, 'Unhandled Rejection at Promise', p);
  })
  .on('uncaughtException', err => {
    // Use your own logger here
    console.error(err, 'Uncaught Exception thrown');

    // Optional: Ensure process will stop after this
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

For a detailed explanation check this [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40867345/catch-all-uncaughtexception-for-node-js-app) here on Stack Overflow. There's also this great blog post:  https://shapeshed.com/uncaught-exceptions-in-node/.

As an extra, check this other one to send emails with the crash information: https://coderwall.com/p/4yis4w/node-js-uncaught-exceptions