# Exiting the process after uncaughtException

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my NodeJS app, whenever it encounters an unhandled exception, I want the process to exit.

However, it seems like according to NodeJS's docs, it does exit by default.
So my question is - should I have something like this in my code?

```
    process
        .on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
            log.error('uncaughtException:', err.message);
            log.error(err.stack);
            process.exit(1);
    });
```

or should I leave the `process.exit(1)` part out of it because it's not needed?

Comment: No, if you add this handler then you must end it with `process.exit(1)`, otherwise your process will not terminate (as you want it to).

Comment: BTW, your entire question - you can simply try it out and see what happens.

Comment: Oh, so by default NodeJS exits, but if i add this custom handler it overrides the default behavior and so i have to explicitly exit?

Comment: Exactly. And like I said, you could easily try it (add a deliberate exception somewhere i your process, and see what happens when you omit the `exit` statement.

Comment: Yeah that's true.. thanks for the clarification! You can post this as an answer if you want and i'll accept it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The part `process.exit(1)` is needed, it does not exit by default and your application may terminate in an unexpected state so you should put `process.exit(1)` in `uncaughtException`

However, it is also a good practice to put event `unhandledRejection` (if you are using `Promise`s in your app)  so you better understand what has happened.

```
process
  .on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
    console.error(reason, 'Unhandled Rejection at Promise', p);
  })
  .on('uncaughtException', err => {
    console.error(err, 'Uncaught Exception thrown');
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Moreover as a side-note(Dario mentions, and quotes official documentation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40867663/6121643), see [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_warning_using_uncaughtexception_correctly))

> The correct use of 'uncaughtException' is to perform synchronous
>   cleanup of allocated resources (e.g. file descriptors, handles, etc)
>   before shutting down the process.