# How do I enable uncaught exception traces from within a node script?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Node can print an uncaught exception trace when it exits due to an uncaught exception. This feature is enabled when I pass `--trace-uncaught` to node.

How do I enable this feature from the source code from within my script?

Perhaps something along the lines of `node.trace_uncaught = true`?

Comment: Seems like this question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40867663/18891587)

Comment: @Jaood_xD It does not, Please read my question carefully.

Comment: You can't apply command line arguments to already running environment, so the only way to reach the same result is to attach listener to process errors as shown in the linked answer

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a general solution to this yet. For now, I'll just (ab)use linux and sh to achieve what I want by adding this line to the top of my script:

```
//bin/true; exec /usr/bin/env node --trace-uncaught "$0" "$@"
```

This line uses sh to launch node with the desired flag. I'll leave this question open in case someone posts a proper cross-platform solution.