# How to apply same error handling logic globally in nest.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, nestjs

*Nest.js*

I wrote logic to handle errors as specified in project requirements.

From the following example, how can I implement the same logic for another route, without rewriting it every time?

```
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get('test/:returnError')
  async test(@Param() param: { returnError: string }) {
    try {
      const shouldThrow = String(param.returnError).toLowerCase() === 'true';

      await this.appService.example(shouldThrow);

      if (shouldThrow) throw new ErrorResponse(401, 'error test', { b: 1 });

      return new SuccessResponse('ok', { test: '1' });
    } catch (error: unknown) {
      if (error instanceof ErrorResponse) return error;

      throw new InternalServerErrorException(error);
    }
  }
}
```

The goal is to apply the same try/catch logic, to other controller routes, without rewriting it.

```
      try {
          ...some logic
     } catch (error: unknown) {
         if (error instanceof ErrorResponse) return error;
         throw new InternalServerErrorException(error);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom exception filter like this:

custom-exception.filter.ts

```
import { ExceptionFilter, Catch, ArgumentsHost, HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
// If ErrorResponse is a custom Error class that you have defined
import { ErrorResponse } from './path-to-your-error-response';

@Catch()
export class CustomExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: any, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
    const status = exception instanceof HttpException ? exception.getStatus() : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    if (exception instanceof ErrorResponse) {
      response.status(status).json({
        statusCode: status,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        path: request.url,
        message: exception.message,
        data: exception.data,
      });
    } else {
      response.status(status).json({
        statusCode: status,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        path: request.url,
        message: exception.message || 'Internal Server Error',
      });
    }
  }
}
```

After that you can register your custom exception filter in main.ts like this:

main.ts

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { CustomExceptionFilter } from './path-to-your-filter/custom-exception.filter';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  // Use the CustomExceptionFilter as a global filter
  app.useGlobalFilters(new CustomExceptionFilter());

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

After all these you can simplify your controller like this:

```
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get('test/:returnError')
  async test(@Param() param: { returnError: string }) {
    const shouldThrow = String(param.returnError).toLowerCase() === 'true';

    await this.appService.example(shouldThrow);

    if (shouldThrow) throw new ErrorResponse(401, 'error test', { b: 1 });

    return new SuccessResponse('ok', { test: '1' });
  }
}
```

By removing the try-catch block, you let the global exception filter handle the exceptions. This can make your controller code cleaner and more focused on the business logic without the need for duplicate/repetitive error-handling code.

Answer (score 0):

I applied it this way.

This will handle any unexpected errors for the Http format.
create file `src/filters/all-exceptions.filter.ts`
reference: https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters

```js
import {
  Catch,
  ArgumentsHost,
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { BaseExceptionFilter } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Request } from 'express';

@Catch()
export class AllExceptionsFilter extends BaseExceptionFilter {
  private excludeHttpStatusList = [404];

  catch(exception: unknown, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    super.catch(exception, host);

    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
    const httpStatus =
      exception instanceof HttpException
        ? exception.getStatus()
        : HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

    if (this.excludeHttpStatusList.includes(httpStatus)) {
      return;
    }

    /*
      send slack message
      send mail
      etc...
    */
  }
}
```

If you want to cover errors that occur at the Node.js level, you can do this.
This content was written at the bottom of `src/main.ts`.
But I think there are times when it doesn't work well.
reference [Catch all uncaughtException for Node js app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40867345/catch-all-uncaughtexception-for-node-js-app)

```js
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  logger.error(
    'uncaughtException Catch ' + JSON.stringify(err.stack ?? err),
    'uncaughtException',
  );
  
  /*
    send slack message
    send mail
    etc...
  */
});
```